Function set td text in <%if statement%> always be called
I want to use C# function to set text in dataRepeater and use if statement in aspx page.
<asp:Repeater ID="dataRepeater" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
           <%if (condition){ %>
              <td>
                  <%#FunctionName(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, ""))%>
              </td>
         <tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

//.cs
protected string FunctionName(){
//
//
//

return string

}


However, any condition always call the C# Function, is that a normal situation or I doing something wrong here, thks.

I'm assuming the closing } is on the aspx page. But your aspx code should work fine and means your if (condition) always returns true. So look into that.

yes it is has the closing }, but I forget to write in the question ,thank you.
My conditiion will able to retruns true or false, but if return false, it will still called the C# function

**ASPX :**

    <asp:Repeater ID="dataRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dataRepeater_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td id="myCell" runat="server">
                    <!-- Initially, you can set an empty text here or a placeholder -->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>


**(.cs file):**

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Bind data to the Repeater here
    dataRepeater.DataSource = yourDataSource; // Replace with your data source
    dataRepeater.DataBind();
}

protected void dataRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if the item is a data item (not the header or footer)
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        // Get the data item (e.g., some object, or DataBinder.Eval)
        var dataItem = e.Item.DataItem;
        
        // Get a reference to the <td> element
        var td = e.Item.FindControl("myCell") as HtmlTableCell;
        
        // Condition based on the dataItem or other logic
        if (YourCondition(dataItem))
        {
            // Call your C# function here
            td.InnerText = FunctionName(dataItem); // Modify the text content conditionally
        }
        else
        {
            td.InnerText = "Default Value"; // Or leave it empty, depending on your need
        }
    }
}

// Your C# function that returns the string you want to set
protected string FunctionName(object dataItem)
{
    // Perform your logic here
    return "Some Result"; // Return the desired value
}

// Example condition method
private bool YourCondition(object dataItem)
{
    // Replace with your actual condition logic
    return true; // Just an example; you should check dataItem here
}

Avoid mixing conditionals with <%# %> data binding expressions for complex logic. Instead, handle such logic in the C# code for better clarity and maintainability.
